# nmcli -- Network Device unavailable on Fedora

Tags: fedora, terminal, wifi, networkmanager, hardware

my network device is "unavailable". When I enter

```
nmcli
```

It returns:

```
wlp0s19f2u2: unavailable
"Netgear WNA1100 150" 
wifi (ath9k_htc) A2:09:0E:06:E3:FA hw mtu 1500
```

"nmcli general" returns:

```
STATE         CONNECTIVITY WIFI-HW WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
disconnected  none         enabled enabled  enabled  enabled
```

ifconfig thinks the device is ethernet (?) But it returns:

```
wlp0s19f2u2: flags=4099<UP BROADCAST MULTICAST> mtu 1500
either a2:09:0e:06:e3:d's txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
```

I have the driver package installed (NetworkManager-wifi)
And I know the device is supported as I had gotten it working using nmcli under the same circumstances

EDIT:

`$ nmcli dev show wlp0s19f2u2` returns:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:     wlp0s19f2u2
GENERAL.TYPE:       wifi
GENERAL.HWDDR:      22:40:F7:7F:AC:9A
GENERAL.MTU         1500
GENERAL.STATE       20 (unavailable) 
GENERAL.CONNECTION: --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:   --
```

**EDIT 2:**

*rfkill* returns:

```
ID TYPE DEVICE SOFT      HARD
0  wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

*rfkill list* returns:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Softlocked: no
         Hardlocked: no
```

Comment: What does `nmcli device show  wlp0s19f2u2` show?

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: And what happens after `nmcli device set wlp0s19f2u2 autoconnect yes`?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. And it does not auto-connect.

Comment: And does `nmcli device show wlp0s19f2u2` output change at all after `nmcli device set wlp0s19f2u2 autoconnect yes`?  I'm wondering if `nmcli dev disconnect wlp0s19f2u2` was issued at some time.  [This would mark `wlp0s19f2u2` as unavailable](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html).

Comment: Nothing Changed before I rebooted except ```GENERAL.HWADDR   96:A5:85:E3:45:75``` Which seems to be changing every time turn my PC on again. Nothing changed after I rebooted except, of course, the GENERAL.HWADDR.

Comment: What does `rfkill` show?

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: Anything interesting or errors in the logs?  E.g., `journalctl -u NetworkManager`, `journalctl -g wlp0s19f2u2`, `journalctl -g ath9k_htc`, `journalctl -g wifi`.  `journalctl` has many options that may help narrow your log searching.  `sudo` might be required to see all log entries.